# Editable webform submissions

Tags: webforms

Requirements for user submissions are:

1. anonymous user is able to submit form data
2. admin can delete any submission
3. admin can edit any field of any submission
4. form can contains fields which are not displayed to user, but admin can edit them
5. admin can sort and filter the submissions according to one field (date type)

There is webform module, but I do not know if it can solve all those requirements (the first one is OK, ofc ;)

Comment: everything can be done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend using the [Webform](https://drupal.org/project/webform) module and the [Webform Report](https://drupal.org/project/webform_report) module.

So

1. webform module
2. webform module
3. webform module
4. when adding a field to your form there are two checkboxes at the bottom (Disabled and Private) which will do what you need it to do.
5. webform report module

Answer (score 1):

Webform is not necessary for the tasks you've outlined.

Simply create a content type, and grant the Anonymous user role access to create content of that type.

To have 'hidden' fields which the admin can still edit, you can either hide those fields with CSS, deny access to them via the `#access` property through a `hook_form_alter()`, or use the Field Permissions module to restrict access to those specific fields. Note that the Field Permissions module has some performance implications.